# The integral equation equivalent to the initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

Determine the integral equation equivalent to the initial value problem
$$
y'(t)= t^2 + y(t)^4;\; y(0) = 1
$$
Could it be $y(t) = 1 + \int_0^t f(s,y(s))\mathrm ds?$ or $y(t) = 1 + \frac{t^3}{3} + \int_0^t f(s,y(s))\mathrm ds?$

As well as, 
the initial value problem 
$$
y''(t) + g(t,y) = 0,\, y(0)=y_0\;\;y'(0) = z_0
$$
which I know can be divided into two first order DE, however, my professor and book don't really explain on how to do this. Is there a standard way to formulate the integral equation from the initial value problem, if so what is it?

Comment: Yes to the first with $f(t,x) = t^2+x^4$, and for the second, let $x_1 = y, x_2 = y'$ which gives $x_2'=-g(t,x_1), x_1' = x_2$.